# Why function zdb(unknown, tid) does not exist in my zombodb extension?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am indexing in zombodb extension in postgres. I want to index like this .

```
CREATE INDEX idx_zdb_masterview
      ON masterview 
   USING zombodb(zdb('masterview', masterview.ctid), zdb(masterview))
```

but it has error :
[Err] ERROR:  function zdb(unknown, tid) does not exist
LINE 3:        USING zombodb(zdb('masterview', masterview.ctid), zdb...
                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

masterView is the name of table.

Comment: "_You might need to add explicit type casts._"

Comment: Hi.  Please report this problem to ZomboDB's github project at https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb, and include details that include the versions of PG, ES, and ZDB you're using, and I'll be glad to help.  I don't use SO and just happen to find this via a link from twitter.